# Nativescript Sidekick Publish to App Store

Tags: nativescript, sidekick

I'm running Sidekick on my Windows 10 machine (64b).

I'm trying to publish my app to the Apple AppStore.
Certificate, provision is all ok.
When I publish, build is made, I can log in when asked and fill in the verication code.

But then I get error 'Spawn Failed'. Googled this error, but didn't find anything.

Erros in the log are:

> [19-03-08 10:52:20.711] (CLI) Build machine host name:
>   administrators-Mac-16.local
>
> [19-03-08 10:52:58.349] Spawn failed.
>
> , Error: Spawn failed.
>       at CloudPublishService.getiOSError (C:\Users\bartad\AppData\Roaming.nativescript-cli\extensions\node_modules\nativescript-cloud\lib\services\cloud-publish-service.js:79:21)
>
> at CloudPublishService.
>   (C:\Users\bartad\AppData\Roaming.nativescript-cli\extensions\node_modules\nativescript-cloud\lib\services\cloud-publish-service.js:96:29)
>
> at Generator.next ()
>
> at fulfilled
>   (C:\Users\bartad\AppData\Roaming.nativescript-cli\extensions\node_modules\nativescript-cloud\lib\services\cloud-publish-service.js:4:58)
>
> at

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong here ?

Thanks
Bart

Answer (score 0):

Issues I encountered:
1) Provisioning was not right. Went back through and checked that each step is for a *Distribution* certificate and profile, not a development profile.
2) I assumed that tns resources generate would create my icons and splashes. It did, but Sidekick ignores them. You must recreate them in Sidekick.